# function that put XML output back to table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

Use Oracle database and `PL/SQL`. I created procedure that generete XML output from table in my base. But, also, need reverse procedure that can put XML output back to table. Finding function to generate XML from table was easy (`dbms_xmlgen.getXML`). But I cannot find reverse function. Please, write here if you know reverse function.

To XML:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE xml_apt
AS 
 doc   clob;
BEGIN
  doc := dbms_xmlgen.getXML('select * from аpt');
  dbms_output.put_line(doc);
END xml_apt;
```

Comment: Something like [XMLSTORE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb_dbmstore.htm) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use DBMS_XMLSave

see: [ORACLE Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_xmlsav.htm)

Probably something like this to update a row....(untested)

```
PROCEDURE yourTableHere_UPDATE (xmlDoc in clob, ret OUT number)
IS
  updCtx DBMS_XMLSave.ctxType;
BEGIN

   updCtx := DBMS_XMLSave.newContext('yourTableHere');

   DBMS_XMLSave.setignorecase(updCtx,1);
   DBMS_XMLSave.setrowtag(updCtx,'yourrowtag');

   DBMS_XMLSave.clearUpdateColumnList(updCtx);
   DBMS_XMLSave.setKeyColumn(updCtx,'ID');

   ret := DBMS_XMLSave.updateXML(updCtx,xmlDoc);
   DBMS_XMLSave.closeContext(updCtx);
   commit;
END;
```